# Expresso Test Recorder not saving the test recorded or not generating test code

Tags: android, android-studio-3.1, expresso

I am using Expresso Test Recorder to generate test cases and code,but when I am trying to save the test recorded, nothing is happening.

I am using Android studio 3.1[image]

Comment: this file will be saved in app/src/androidTest/java and in that with the package name , did you check here after save  ?

Comment: Yes, I checked in the app/src/androidTest/java  folder, Test file was not present. Event in the git change list, file is not listed.